# Error trying to install package for iris dataset

Tags: r, installation, dataset, package

I just installed R on my new computer and want to install some packages. But im running into some strange errors when doing this.

When I do this:

```
install.packages(iris)
```

I get the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Marc/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
ackage ‘iris’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

I especially dont get the unspecified lib part as I just set it  (.libPaths("C:/Users/Marc/Desktop/R/Library"))

Any thoughts on what is causing this error?

Comment: as written in `help(install.packages)` if you don't specify the `lib` argument then it is installed in the first element of `.libPaths()`

Comment: and are you sure that there is an `iris` package ? Don't you mean the `iris` dataset ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no `iris` **package** (as @etienne said). If you do `?iris` (or google for it) it tells you that `iris` **dataset** comes with `datasets` package.

I thought `datasets` package came bundled with R.
(If it doesn't, or if yours got corrupted somehow, `install.packages('datasets', ...`)