# How to stop the same figure numbers appearing in my rmarkdown document

Tags: ggplot2, r-markdown, figure, tikz

I generated several figures using different kinds of commands such as tikz, rmarkdown chunck, ggplot2 like the following. Unfortunately, they all are generated with the same figure number as "Figure 1". Do you have any suggestion to resolve the issue?
Here in the following I generate a reproducible example. Please refer to the following codes for your reference.

````
---
title: "demo" 
author: 
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.2
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \usepackage{bbm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{indentfirst}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}}
---
```{r fig.align="center", fig.cap="\\label{fig:figure4}Trends", warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
    
options(scipen=999)  # turn-off scientific notation like 1e+48
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())  # pre-set the bw theme.
data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")
gg <- ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + 
  geom_point(aes(col=state, size=popdensity)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) + 
  xlim(c(0, 0.1)) + 
  ylim(c(0, 500000)) + 
  labs(subtitle="Area Vs Population", 
       y="Population", 
       x="Area", 
       title="Scatterplot", 
       caption = "Source: midwest")

plot(gg)
```
    




```{r fig.align="center", fig.cap="\\label{fig:figure1} figure 1 "}
library(datasets)
library(tseries)
data("AirPassengers")
passengers <- AirPassengers
plot(passengers, main = "Monthly Air Passenger Traffic")
```

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.32 ] (66.5,28.97) -- (248.5,28.97) -- (248.5,137) -- (66.5,137) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.25 ] (62.5,265.61) -- (250.25,265.61) -- (250.25,356.79) -- (62.5,356.79) -- cycle ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\footnotesize Flow Diagram 1}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.32 ] (66.5,28.97) -- (248.5,28.97) -- (248.5,137) -- (66.5,137) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.25 ] (62.5,265.61) -- (250.25,265.61) -- (250.25,356.79) -- (62.5,356.79) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\footnotesize Flow Diagram2}
\label{fig:figure3}
\end{figure}

```

Look at \cref{fig:figure1}, \cref{fig:figure2}, \cref{fig:figure3} and \cref{fig:figure4}.
````

Comment: Latex does not number the figures, it numbers the captions. Your figures need a caption if you want them to increase the figure counter. And the label need to be after (or in) the caption

Comment: Thanks, for clarification, could you tell me where I should move `\label{}` to and what do I have to do about `\label{}` inside `fig.cap`?

Comment: You should add a caption `\caption{some text here}` to each figure environment

Comment: In fact I did but nothing changes. Could you see my updated posting?

Comment: ... then please make a compilable [mre], including a header etc which allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure please give me some time to do so. Thanks!

Comment: I modified the original post, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Don't you need some \`\`\` around your code parts and maybe some header with an output option, loading some packages etc?

Comment: I did it again. Still do I need to put some more options here?

Comment: Oh maybe I can put my YAML heading so that reproducible example may be more complete. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: If I guess a likely header and correct the typo in the label name, your code works fine. You should really add your header and make a compilable [mre] in one codeblock.

Comment: How about now. I add pretty much everything I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you are missing the `cleveref` package
- there is a typo in `fig:figuare1`
- and according to [Error trying to install package for iris dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517026/error-trying-to-install-package-for-iris-dataset) , there is no `iris` library

---

````
---
title: "demo" 
author: 
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
link-citations: yes
toc: false
biblio-style: apalike    
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 12pt
linestretch: 1.2
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \usepackage{bbm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{indentfirst}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{cleveref}}
---

```{r fig.align="center", fig.cap="\\label{fig:figure1} figure 1 "}
library(datasets)
library(tseries)
data("AirPassengers")
passengers <- AirPassengers
plot(passengers, main = "Monthly Air Passenger Traffic")
```

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.32 ] (66.5,28.97) -- (248.5,28.97) -- (248.5,137) -- (66.5,137) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.25 ] (62.5,265.61) -- (250.25,265.61) -- (250.25,356.79) -- (62.5,356.79) -- cycle ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\footnotesize Flow Diagram 1}
\label{fig:figure2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.32 ] (66.5,28.97) -- (248.5,28.97) -- (248.5,137) -- (66.5,137) -- cycle ;
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=0.25 ] (62.5,265.61) -- (250.25,265.61) -- (250.25,356.79) -- (62.5,356.79) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\footnotesize Flow Diagram2}
\label{fig:figure3}
\end{figure}

```{r fig.align="center", fig.cap="\\label{fig:figure4}Trends", warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)

qplot(Sepal.Length, data = iris, size = Petal.Width)
```

Look at \cref{fig:figure1}, \cref{fig:figure2}, \cref{fig:figure3} and \cref{fig:figure4}.
````

[image]

Comment: thanks, could you briefly tell me main difference between yours and my code?

Comment: @jck21 I just added a list at the top

Comment: Thank you. Everything works fine except the first ggplot (in my edited post) doesn't seem to be properly counted. It shows like Figure 1, Figure 1, Figure 2, Figure 3, Figure 4,.... Could you take a look?

Comment: In fact, my document start with ggplot, so I moved the last ggplot to the top as my figure 1. I also changed it from gplot to ggplot.

Comment: If I, again, fix the typo, the bib file I don't have and the missing package, and then go ahead and  fix the indentation of your `fig:figure4`, I get them numbered correctly. Please edit your question so one can use the code and reproduce the problem without having to fix anything else first

Comment: I think I did as you request, hope it works for anyone who sees this. Thanks. Still I am trying why mine doesn't fully work, but I guess I will figure it out soon. thanks.

Comment: @jck21 The typo `fig:figuare1` is still in your question. There is no indication that you load the cleveref package (maybe in the files you don't show us, but we can't know.)

Comment: Okay, let me know if there's anything still missing.

Comment: @jck21 You can't load cleveref like this. Rmarkdown automatically loads hyperref after the header includes, so you need to trick rmarkdown like I did in my answer.

Comment: Ok, the code now works fine. I get `Look at fig. 2, fig. 3, fig. 4 and fig. 1.` as expected. What do you get?